# Referring to a person, should I use the capital letter for "Fascist"?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, capitalization

As I understand, the word Fascism must be capitalised, while the adjective fascist should not.  But what if "Fascist" is used as a noun?

Eg: "The headmaster was enlisted in the National Fascist Party and therefore he was a Fascist"

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no reason why either the adjective or the noun should bear an initial capital letter, unless it forms part of the name of something, such as the organisation you mention.

Comment: That is to say, whether the headmaster was a Fascist is a matter of record; whether he was a fascist is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Perhaps the most obvious distinction is between the common adjective 'liberal' and the proper-noun (and proper-adjective) 'Liberal'.